# Percentage of time one projected value will be higher than another given means and standard deviations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gambling

I'm hoping someone might know the correct mathematical way to approach this. The best way I can frame it is in terms of sports betting. Let's say I project the New York Yankees to score 5 runs today, while Vegas projects them to score 4 runs. I know the mean and the standard deviation for my projected runs and Vegas's projected runs for the entire population of teams.

How often would I expect the Yankees to score above Vegas's 4 run estimate, and how often would I expect the team to score below 4 runs?

I'm fairly certain there's an easy formula to figure this out, and it's one of those things that feels like it's on the tip of my tongue but I can't remember. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would you like the probability that the Yankees score above $4$ or above Vegas's 4 run estimate (which is a random variable)?

Comment: Is the data normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, distribution is fairly normal.  I'm not sure I know the distinction between 4 and Vegas's 4 run estimate being a random variable.  That number can change based on whatever Vegas thinks, and I'd want to be able to calculate it against whatever number they have.